# I am trying to create POST data for web scraping using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, beautifulsoup

I have a form-input like:

```html
<PRE>
<FORM>
<INPUT name="field_RecordingDateID-StartDate" id="field_RecordingDateID-StartDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="date" value="">
<INPUT name="field_RecordingDateID-EndDate" id="field_RecordingDateID-EndDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="date" value="">
<input type="submit" value="search">
</FORM>
</PRE>
```

I am try to create dictionary as

```
payload = dict(field_RecordingDateID-StartDate = "10-08-2016",
   field_RecordingDateID-EndDate ="12-08-2016")
```

And I need to send post request so that I can get the result through Python requests.
I am using

```
r = requests.get(url,data=payload)
```

Currently I am getting error as 'Can't assigned the value to operator' in console.
The error is at creating dictionary.
Can you help me?

Comment: How are you getting the form data?

Comment: Form data are: field_RecordingDateID_StartDate:2017-03-01
field_RecordingDateID_EndDate:2017-03-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a small problem in your code. Actually the correct way to define a dictionary is will be like this.

```
payload = {"field_RecordingDateID-StartDate" :"10-08-2016",
                                "field_RecordingDateID-EndDate" :"12-08-2016"}
```

Comment: yes, its worked.  I was following the dict() function which was creating problem.  I haven't tried this way.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a valid identifier. Try to create payload dict as:

```
StartDate = 'field_RecordingDateID-StartDate'
EndDate = 'field_RecordingDateID-EndDate'
payload = dict(StartDate = '10-08-2016', EndDate = '12-08-2016')
```

and post your data as:

```
r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
```

Comment: Hi its not giving me any result